# Not able to see tab text in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

Im using the following code in JADE and I dont see the tabs text in the navigation bar,what can be the problem here,I try to play with the indentation without success I guess Im missing something basic.please assist

```
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
        script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
        body 
          div 
           nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
           .container
             .navbar-header
               button.navbar-toggle(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1')
                        span.sronly
                        span.icon-bar
                        span.icon-bar
                        span.icon-bar
                #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
                  ul.nav.navbar-nav
                   li
                    a(href='/recipes/bbq')  Tab1
                   li
                    a(href='/recipes/bbq')  Tab2
                    div.container
                    block content
```

here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jo1nnrp4/3/

This is the view ,I want to see tab1& tab2 in the navigation bar and put the arrival text in the gray area,how can I do that?[image]

**Update**

```
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
        script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
    body 
        div 
           nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
           .container
             .navbar-header
               button.navbar-toggle(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1')
                        span.sronly
                        span.icon-bar
                        span.icon-bar
                        span.icon-bar
                #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
                  ul.nav.navbar-nav
                   li
                    a(href='/recipes/bbq')  Tab1
                   li
                    a(href='/recipes/bbq')  Tab2
        div.container
            block content
```

This is the second file/view which I call in the url and put the arrival data in the page

extends layout

```
block content
    .jumbotron
    h1= title
    ul
        each flight, index in arrivals
            - landed = new Date(flight.actualArrive)
            li= flight.number + ': ' + flight.origin + '-' + landed
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or something where we can see the rendered html/css.

Comment: @ZackTanner- HI Zack,not sure how to add the bootstrap refernace but here is JSfiddle with the renderd html http://jsfiddle.net/jo1nnrp4/1/

Comment: @ZackTanner- this is the new fiddle which I want to add the tab's to the navbar and the list to the gray area ,how should I adopt the code http://jsfiddle.net/jo1nnrp4/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. Try using the same amount of indentation per level, for example a tab character or for example four spaces. The indentation between `html` and `head` is four characters, where its two characters between `body` and `div`. Keeping this consistent makes it more clear which element is a child of which parent.
2. The content shouldn't be part of the navigation. You can fix this by changing the indentation of the second last line, the `div.container`, by giving it the same level as the first `div` in the body. In your case 4 + 4 + 2 = 10 spaces should do it.
3. The `block content` should be a child of the `div.container`, as you want the content to be contained in the `div.container`. To do so give it four additional spaces of indentation like this:

   ```
         div.container
             block content
   ```
4. The `div.container` should be a child of the `nav` element. Currently it exists on the same level. To fix this you need to give all lines after `nav` some additional indentation (except for the ones you fixed in 3. obviously).

Comment: Thanks! I did what you suggest and still I dont see the tab's in the  and the list in the gray area,can you take a look again and se e what am i missing,see my post i've updated it.

Comment: you can have a look at this JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jo1nnrp4/8/ ,maybe I need to put the tab diffently ?the color ? becouse I think they already in the navbar but I dont see them?any idea how to change it that I will able to see them?

Comment: I added a 4th bullet. http://jade-lang.com/demo/ looks nice to play around with Jade templates and the resulting html. Perhaps that's something to investigate (although I couldn't get the `block content` to work there).

Comment: Thanks voted up for the help,please see my update post with the second jade file  which I call in the browser and show the block content

Comment: 5. Make sure the `h1` and `ul` have more indentation then the `.jumbotron` as you want them both to become a child of the jumbotron (they should be shown inside the jumbotron right?). You're welcome!

Comment: I did that and still I dont see them in the gray box,in addition I dont see the tab's text,any other idea?

Comment: The only thing that might be wrong that I can think of is indentation in Jade and how the elements are nested in the resulting html. Perhaps it's an idea to split it into two problems, first try to get the html correct (http://codepen.io might be easier than jsfiddle as you directly see the result) and afterward try implementing that html in Jade. Next to that I'm out of ideas. Sorry mate :(

Comment: One last question are you familiar with node.js?If I dont want to use jade there is other way to do the UI?

Comment: I created a few tiny command line utilities in node.js, but never a web application. There should be plenty of templating engines though, perhaps take a look at [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)? They are closer to the resulting html, so that might be easier.